# VIM Project and Tabs

Tags: vim, ide, console, tabs, project

Is there a possibility to combine the Project Plugin with Tabs?

If i open a file in my Project Explorer, i want to open it in a new tab ... :)

Comment: hm ... okay nerdTree looks nice.. but: is it also possible to open the files in tabs on the right split?

Comment: @unknown (yahoo) - you mean, for example, where you're clicking on the files on the left, and viewing them on the right. so you can preview them, for instance ? possible, but hard. try looking at the ":help preview"

Comment: no not like that... if i click or open a file in the Tree, it will oben on the right.. but opens a tab on the right.. so the previous file and the current are open and i can tab through

Answer (score 4):

You have to hack this plugin yourself (I do not think it would be difficult) or email the author and kindly ask him to do it.

I would also suggest [NERDTree](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1658) as a Project replacement (it can open files in tabs).

Comment: thats a great plugin it can also open files in a split window.

Answer (score 3):

For open file of project in other tab use
Leader T
\T

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue.  For now I'vee learned to use buffers.
To expand on the buffers post above, when you open a new file the Project plugin hides the previous file but it is still an active buffer.  ':ls' will list the buffers, switch to a buffer with ':b #' where # is the number of the buffer or split the screen and open a buffer with ':sb #'.  Not quite as convenient as tabs but it works until a better solution comes up.

Answer (score 0):

If you open a new buffer window, you can click to open in that buffer.

Comment: Unfortunately, the NERDTree plugin does not like to play nice with the project plugin.

Answer (score 0):

If you have macVim or gVim of some sort, you can open a finder/explorer window at the project's tree and drag and drop files into windows/tabs.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same desire, so [I created a portable configuration called Vim.ana](https://github.com/NewAlexandria/vim.ana).

It doesn't have many opinions that you can't change easily in the `.vimrc`

Sauce on layout at the project homepage